# Maven - Install an artifact to the Nexus repository

Tags: maven, build, build-process, nexus

I have a problem currently when i run the command mvn install, the artifact is installed in my local repository (i.e. in %HOME/.m2 folder) but not in the Nexus repository.

I know with Nexus i can add an artifact manually using the GUI but is there a way to do install the artifact as part of the mvn command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're seeing is normal behavior in the [standard maven lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html). The `install` phase is only supposed to install the artifact locally. You need to run `deploy`, which comes after `install`. That's when maven uploads artifacts to a remote repository. The remote repo for deployment is configured in the [distribution management section of the pom](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Distribution_Management).